# How to raise an exception in Snowflake

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried following code

```
try {
        if ( isDuplicate == 'Y' ){
        throw new Error("This is a duplicate record");
        }   
        else {
           snowflake.execute({sqlText:  `INSERT INTO TEMP2_Table SELECT Id, Name FROM 
           TEMP1_Table;`});
        }
} catch (err) {
            throw err;
       }
```

I needed to raise an exception when particular ID is going to insert as duplicate record. I used JavaScript Stored procedure.

Then I got following error

```
ERROR -> Technical Error Occured FAIL_CODE : undefined
STATE : undefined
MESSAGE : This is a duplicate record
STACK_TRACE : undefined
QUERY_ID : 01aaf508-3200-ad9f-0000-631d265e1b7e
EXECUTED_SP : myproc
EXECUTION_SATUS : FAILURE
```

How can I fix this error

Anyone can help me

Thank You

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/exceptions

Comment: You may need to rewrite your code -- https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D53r0000BhUpEkCQK/try-catch-in-snowflake-stored-proc-using-sql-language

Comment: @KoushikRoy Your links are for SQL Scripting and not JS procedures. Lochana, if you need a custom exception in JS you can simply do: if ( isDuplicate == 'Y' ){ throw "This is a duplicate record"; }. See the example from [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript#catching-an-error-using-try-catch)

Comment: In case it needs clarity once you have read the link @Sergiu provided, SPs don't return errors, specifically; they return whatever you code them to return - whether that is an error message, a success code or a result value